# having a problem with jquery votes just like stackoverflow votes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

i have this jquery code with an ajax request that works fine, but the jquery is not displaying the results(vote_count) and changing the upvote image, just like stackoverflow:

jquery code:

```
$(function(){
    $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
    //get the id
    the_id = $(this).attr('id');

    //the main ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "action=vote_up&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
        url: "ajax/votes.php",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            //echo the votes count
            $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);
            //replace the new vote count
            $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();
            //replace the image with active arrow
            $("#vote_up"+the_id).attr("src", "img/upvoteActive.png");

        }
    });
});
```

the html code:

```
<li class ="record">
<span class="vote_count">$net_vote</span> 

  <a href='#' class='vote_up' id=$id><img src="img/uparrow.png"></a>

  <a href='#' class='vote_down' id=$id><img src="img/downarrow.png"></a>
</li>
```

to clarify everything again, the ajax request is fine its upvoting the right answer, the problem is in the success bit of the ajax, the new vote count is not showing, and the image is not being replaced to an active arrow(just like stack overflower) thanks :))

Comment: What is the 'msg'? Meaning what is its content. As far as I'm aware jQuery usually wraps this into an object. Thus you'll need to do something like msg.data. If you have firebug installed do `console.log(msg)` and see whats being returned.

Comment: it returns the number of counts calculated from the database, and echos them on the ajax/votes.php file, i checked on firebug, and console reponse is correct, its just not fading in the vote count on the actual html page!! :)) so long i know sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors in the `success` callback are all wrong. You have `<span class="vote_count">...</span>` but then try to update it's value as if it had an id: `$("span#votes_count"+the_id)...`

You probably want your code more like:

```
success: function(msg) {
  //echo the votes count
  $("span.vote_count#"+the_id).html(msg);
  //replace the new vote count
  $("span.vote_count#"+the_id).fadeIn();
  //replace the image with active arrow
  $(".vote_up#"+the_id).attr("src", "img/upvoteActive.png");
}
```

So as you can see, you'll also want to add the id of the object into the `.vote_count` element as well.

*Update*:

To be clearer, here is the updated markup:

```
<span class="vote_count" id="$id">$net_vote</span> 
<a href='#' class='vote_up' id="$id"><img src="img/uparrow.png" /></a>
<a href='#' class='vote_down' id="$id"><img src="img/downarrow.png" /></a>
```

And here is the updated javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
    //get the id
    var the_id = $(this).attr('id');

    //the main ajax request
    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      data: "action=vote_up&id=" + the_id,
      url: "ajax/votes.php",
      success: function( msg ) {
        $("span.vote_count#"+the_id).html(msg).fadeIn();
        $(".vote_up#" + the_id + " img").attr("src", "img/upvoteActive.png");
      }
    } );
  } );
} );
```

Comment: thanks the the vote_count is working hooooray thank you , +upvote from me!! but the image is still not changing

Comment: Ah ha, missed that. Check newest edit. You weren't selecting the actual image that's within the anchor.

Comment: loool, its still not working, i dont why it wnt change!! hahaha

Comment: Then your image must not exist? Use firebug... does the `img` element's `src` change at least?

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery code you use `#votes_count` but the html does not have an id but a `vote_count` class (*without the s*).

So it should read `span.vote_count`

same with the upvote, you use an id to target it but it has a class..

Comment: so whats the solution, i dnt really get what you mean!! sorry

Answer (score -1):

You were incorrectly targetting the spans, and also, sending get parameters over a post request. I have fixed below:

```
 $(function(){
        $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
        //get the id
        the_id = $(this).attr('id');

    //the main ajax request
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {'action' : 'vote_up','id' : $(this).attr("id")} // here
                url: "ajax/votes.php",
                success: function(msg)
                {
                                    //echo the votes count
                    $("span.vote_count").html(msg); //here
                    //replace the new vote count
                    $("span.vote_count").fadeIn(); // here
                    //replace the image with active arrow
                               $(".vote_up").find(the_id).attr("src", "img/upvoteActive.png"); // and here

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: That's not it, jQuery serializes an object passed as data into what you see in his post anyway. jQuery also knows where to put params in POST vs GET requests. Also, you forgot a comma at the end of the `data: ...` line :)

Comment: The main AJAX call does, but .post doesn't

Comment: like i have stated before there is nothing wrong with the ajax request, its the jquery fade.id and changing the image after the success call that is the problem :))